# Changing GUI components in a loop?

Tags: java

I'm creating a slot machine program and trying to change the color of 3 different text boxes when the spin button is clicked.

I have an array of color objects, so whenever I want to change the color I just use my Random object to do x = rand.nextInt ( 5) and then text1. setBackground ( colors [ x]) and something similar with the others.

I tried using a loop in a method to get different random numbers each time, then change the background each time, with different random numbers, therefore giving me different colors in my color array.

I tried using Thread.sleep in the loop so the color change is noticeable, and printed out the random ints each time to make sure it was working properly. And is was. But for some reason it doesn't want to change anything on the GUI until the loop ends. So if it runs through 10 times, it only changes the color once - at the end.

Why is this? I tried splitting into different threads, giving the color changing to another thread while the main thread is sleeping, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us this portion of your code?

Comment: Are you using swing? If so, do not use Thread.sleep but rather look into [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: The Thread.sleep() is blocking the `Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)` so the GUI can't repaint itself until the entire loop is finished executing, so you only see the last color change. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.